# run Microsoft Word throw windows service Error

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, service

I tried to run Microsoft Word using windows service, Windows API.

The following code throw an error

```
uint sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
var result = WTSQueryUserToken((UInt32)sessionId, out p);
bool result = DuplicateTokenEx(p, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, TokenImpersonation, 1, out duplicate);
result = CreateProcessAsUser(duplicate, processExe, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, (UInt32)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref info, out procInfo);
```

Microsoft Word opened but can not access any folders and show an error:
[image: word opened error]

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: There's no need to duplicate the token as `WTSQueryUserToken` already returns a primary token. Also you are not doing any error checking. As word is a GUI application you probably also shouldn't pass `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the token from `WTSQueryUserToken` which is not required since it already returns a primary user token (which is required for `CreateProcessAsUser`).

From the error message it looks like the launched process (word) does not have access to the user profile. This is probably because you are passing `TokenImpersonation` flag instead of `TokenPrimary`.

So if you remove the call to `DuplicateTokenEx` it should be fine but the real issue is using `TokenImpersonate` rather than `TokenPrimary`.

Your code should be something like (not tested, just typed directly here):

```
sessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
if (sessionId != 0xffffffff)
{
   if (WTSQueryUserToken((UInt32)sessionId, out p))
   {
      var result = CreateProcessAsUser(p, processExe, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref info, out procInfo);
      CloseHandle(p);
      if (result)
      {
         CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);
         CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: also need use `CreateEnvironmentBlock` for token and `CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT` flag

Comment: Thank you Remko for your answer but I still get the same error

Comment: Thanks RbMm for your comment CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT flag for which API ?

Comment: Try launching a command prompt instead of word, using the service. Are you able to access the file in the error message? You might have an issue loading the profile. If that is ok, have you tried loading word directly from the console? Does that work without errors?

Comment: I tried to open bat file that run word the same problem , I tried use CreateEnvironmentBlock with original token I get "The parameter is incorrect" error CreateProcessAsUser(p, processExe, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, (UInt32)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, lpEnvToken, null, ref info, out procInfo); and also I tried with out CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE